# Magento admin panel is unable to load

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.6, magento

I have a problem with my magento admin that when i give my IP before it shows that "There has been processing your request and it shows error log number"... Then I did as suggested in the link

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/magento-install-error-exception-printing-is-disabled

but now it shows a blank screen..

how to get back my admin panel..

Comment: Can't you look up the error trace in var/reports/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento install error - Exception printing is disabled

Here is a known error which can occur when installing Magento:
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Here is the solution:

1. Navigate to the "errors" folder.
2. Change `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`. You should now see a new list of crazy errors all over the Magento page - this is okay.
3. Open `magento/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` and look for:

   protected $_options = array(
   'cache_dir' => 'null',

Change it to:

```
protected $_options = array(
'cache_dir' => 'tmp/',
```

And **save** it.

Now the final step is to go create a tmp folder in the root Magento folder.
    That's it.

Comment: DO NOT EVER try to do what @PavanKumar says, on production shop, especially 1 and 2, otherwise one day you will find your database password in google. if you want to know how? magento throws away error output with databaser name, user and password in some cases... and 3 as well, useless to subject. instead try to read your error logs. you have answered incorrectly, you better update or comment your 1st post...

Comment: I have a doubt that How the database password goes out with the suggestion what I was made?? Actually it was from the other website.. Everyone accepted this answer in that site..

Comment: ("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name",$username,$password);
PDO->__construct('mysql:model=mys...', 'PavanKumar', 'password', Array)